# Print String words reverse - edge cases

Tags: java, string

I try to create a function that changes the String from `StackOverflow is the best.` to `best. the is StackOverflow`.

I wrote the following function, but can't seem to fix the spaces in the `result` string. For some reason, I receive `best.the is Stackoverflow`. There is no space between `best.` & `the`, and there is an extra space after `StackOverflow`.

I could add a variable that represents space and use `if`'s in the edge cases, but I believe that there is a better way to do so.

Could anyone help me figure this out?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "Stackoverflow is the best.";

    String result = change(str);

    System.out.println(result);
}



private static String change(String str) {
    String result = "";

    int i1 = str.length()-1;
    int i2 = str.length();

    for (i1 = str.length(); i1 >= 0; i1--) {

        if (i1 ==0 || str.charAt(i1-1) == ' ') {

            result = result.concat(str.substring(i1, i2));
            i2 = i1;
        }           
    }

return result;
}
```

Comment: Have you thought about using `str.split(" ")` and working with the resulting array instead?

Comment: The expected result mentioned is not String reverse. String reverse for your input will be **".tseb eht si wolfrevOkcatS"**. Do you need to String reverse or do a word reverse on group of words stored as String ?

Comment: @AravindReddyP Let me rephrase - I should do a word reverse on group of words stored as String

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code? In my opinion, being able to debug your code is an essential skill if you want to be a professional programmer. Are you using an IDE (like _Eclipse_, for example) ? Most IDEs include a debugger and have accompanying documentation on how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way i could think of without using `if's` is :

```
        String line = "Stackoverflow is the best.";
        String delimeter = " ";
        final String[] words = line.split(delimeter);
        String reversedLine = "";
        for(int i = words.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            reversedLine += words[i] + delimeter;
        }
        // remove the delimeter present at last of line
        reversedLine = reversedLine.substring(0, reversedLine.length() - 1);
        System.out.println(reversedLine);
```

Answer (score 0):

To generate the output as you have mentioned, I would approach a problem in this way:

```
class Solution {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "StackOverflow is the best.";
    String[] arr = str.split(" ");
    System.out.print(arr[arr.length-1]);
    for(int i = arr.length - 2; i >= 0; i--){
      System.out.print(" "+arr[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

The only reason to your problem is that you haven't added the space after the '.'
Try using `String str = "Stackoverflow is the best. ";`

Hope it helped... :)

Comment: I can't change the input

Comment: In an 'if' statement, you can add a check for periods and then concatenate a blank space later... It would not change the input as such.

`if(result.charAt(i)=='.')` 
add a blank space after...